# Showing holomorphicity of $f(z)=\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(z-n)^{-n}}{n!}$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{N}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I would like to construct a function that is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{N}$ with a pole of order $n$ at each positive integer $n$. My idea was to take the following $f$:
$$f(z)=\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(z-n)^{-n}}{n!}.$$
Is it clear that $f$ has a pole of order $n$ at each positive integer $n$. I would now like to show that it is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{N}$. I believe it should be sufficient to show that the series representation of $f$ converges uniformly on every compact subset of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{N}$. Indeed, for a fixed $R, \varepsilon>0$ let
$$B(R,\varepsilon)=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|\le R\right\} \cap \{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z-n|\ge \varepsilon \operatorname{for all} n\in\mathbb{N} \}\subset \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{N},$$
where $B(R, \varepsilon)$ is compact.

For any $z\in B(R,\varepsilon)$, we have that $|z-n|\ge \varepsilon$, thus $|z-n|^{-n}\le \varepsilon^{-n}$ but
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\varepsilon^{-n}}{n!}$$
converges for any $\varepsilon>0$, thus by the M-test, we have uniform convergence and $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{N}$.

My questions are:

(1) is the proof correct

(2) What are alternative ways of proving the desired statemnt?

Comment: You should state explicitly that any compact subset of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{N}$ is contained in $B(R,\epsilon)$ for some $R$ and $\epsilon$.